# Faster way to split JSON objects into multiple data frames?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr

I am working on a project where I need to take JSON object that I received from an API into several data frames that I will eventually load into a database.  When I initially convert the JSON object into a data frame, several of the columns end up as lists of list.

My goal is to split these lists of lists off from the data frame into their own individual frames along with the associated ID# so I can join subsets of the tables when querying.

Since I am working with large amounts of data, the way I am doing that seems far too slow. My guess is that there is a faster way to do it using dplyr or some other package but I do not know how to go about it. My current code is as follows

```r
dframe <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file("filename"))

#[[2]][[x]] is location of s_id and [[15]][[x]] is location of m_s_name lists
m_to_frame = function(dframe){
  s_ids= c()
  for(x in (1:length(dframe$s_id))){
     s_ids = c(s_ids,rep(dframe[[2]][[x]],length(dframe[[15]][[x]])))
  }
  msc = purrr::flatten(dframe$m_s_name)
  return(tibble(s_id=s_ids,m_s_name=msc))
}
m = m_to_frame(dframe)
```

The JSON is formatted as follows

```
[{"u_id":"",
    "s_id":"",
    "created_at":"",
    "s_name":"",
    "text":"",
    "display_text_width":"",
    "reply_to_s_id":"",
    "reply_to_u_id":"",
    "reply_to_s_name":"",
    "is_q":false,
    "is_r":false,
    "fav_count":15,
    "r_count":1,
    "tags":["",""],
    "m_s_name":["",""]
}]
```

Comment: You need to share structure of your json.

Comment: That's a good point. The post has been edited to include the structure.

Comment: Can you share some sample data as well. Basically, a sample `dframe` of length 2 with value for keys: `s_id` and `m_s_name`.